# Oracledb (NodeJS) working when I create a new pool each time but not without. Need it to use already created pool

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, async-await, node-oracledb

Followed a tutorial to get this working for stored procedures inside of Oracle. I have my GET/SELECT statements working correctly where based on the user making the GET call it changes the pool so that the SELECTs are from the correct user.

Pool creations that work for GET/SELECT

```js
async function initialize() {

   await oracledb.createPool({
    user: 'user1',
    password: 'pass1',
    connectString: 'oracledb.website/dev',
    poolAlias: 'pool1'
  });

  await oracledb.createPool({
    user: 'user2',
    password: 'pass2',
    connectString: 'oracledb.website/dev',
    poolAlias: 'pool2'
  });

}
```

The tutorial I followed for stored procedures can be found here: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/using-dbmsoutput-with-nodejs-and-node-oracledb

You will see that in this example he has a new pool being created for every request.

```
oracledb.createPool(
  dbconfig,
  function(err, pool) {
if (err)
console.error(err.message)
else
doit(pool);
});
var doit = function(pool) {
```

Note that the dbConfig used above is an array like:

```
dbconfig.hrPool.user = 'user3';
dbconfig.hrPool.password = 'pass3';
dbconfig.hrPool.connectString = 'oracle.site/dev';
```

This will cause issues if you specify a poolAlias and you will quickly end up trying to create a pool alias that already exists with an error like:

```
"NJS-046: poolAlias "pool1" already exists in the connection pool cache.
```

I have attempted to update this code myself but I am not familiar enough with asyc/waterfalls/callbacks to get it to keep going.

What I attempted is below (it never actually runs anything):

```js
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  async.waterfall(
    [
      function(cb) {
          oracledb.getConnection('pool1');
      },
      enableDbmsOutput,
      createDbmsOutput,
      fetchDbmsOutputLine
    ],
    function (err, conn, cb) {
      if (err) {
        console.error("In waterfall error cb: ==>", err, "<== THIS IS WHERE THE ORACLE ERROR WILL SHOW!"); 
                 // Release the Oracle Connection
        conn.release(function (err) {
          if (err) console.error(err.message); 
         });
    }
    }
  );

var enableDbmsOutput = function (conn, cb) {
  conn.execute(
    "BEGIN DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(NULL); END;",
    function(err) { return cb(err, conn); });
};

var createDbmsOutput = function (conn, cb) {
  console.log('I NEVER MAKE IT HERE')
 conn.execute(query
 ,function(err) { return cb(err, conn); });
};

var fetchDbmsOutputLine = function (conn, cb) {
  conn.execute(
    "BEGIN DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE(:ln, :st); END;",
    { ln: { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.STRING, maxSize: 32767 },
      st: { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.NUMBER } },
    function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        return cb(err, conn);
      } else if (result.outBinds.st == 1) {
        return cb(null, conn);  // no more output
      } else {
        resolve(result);

        return fetchDbmsOutputLine(conn, cb);
      }
    });
};
})
}
```

Would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

The blog you quoted is a command-line script and only creates a pool once.  That happens at the start of the script.  It also is an old blog post.  All its async module calls and JS callbacks should/would now be replaced by Node.js's newer `async`/`await` syntax.  Also avoid using `Promise()` directly - code gets too confusing.

Since you are creating some kind of web listener, you should create the pool during app start up, but not for each web request.

Check the node-oracledb example [webapp.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/webapp.js).

```js
async function init() {
  try {
    await oracledb.createPool({
      user: dbConfig.user,
      password: dbConfig.password,
      connectString: dbConfig.connectString
    });

    // Create HTTP server and listen on port httpPort
    const server = http.createServer();
    server.on('error', (err) => {
      console.log('HTTP server problem: ' + err);
    });
    server.on('request', (request, response) => {
      handleRequest(request, response);
    });
    await server.listen(httpPort);
    console.log("Server is running at http://localhost:" + httpPort);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("init() error: " + err.message);
  }
}

async function handleRequest(request, response) {

...  // Your code to handle each web request goes here.

}


init();
```

You may also wait to review the PL/SQL procedure example [plsqlproc.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/plsqlproc.js).